# О бабках (бабка надвое сказала, к бабке не ходи и проч.)

Tags: этимология, семантика

"Бабка надвое сказала", "к бабке не ходи". 
Возник спор относительно значения "бабок" в этих и подобных выражениях. Собственно, возник он в связи с переводом. В русском есть два значения слова "бабка" - знахарка, колдунья и бабушка. Даже на украинском переводы уже не будут омонимичными. А в русском, похоже, граница между значениями несколько стерлась.

Дело еще осложняется тем, что второе значение сейчас признается разговорным, едва ли не просторечным. Хотя в советские времена семейный кодекс свободно оперировал терминами "дед, бабка, тётка" и только ими. В российском ГК они заменены на дедушку, бабушку и тётю.  Получается, что "бабка" в одном значении устаревает. Не произошло ли переосмысление значения и в приведенных фразах? Ведь для меня там "бабка" - это именно символ бабушки, бабуси, умудренной годами и опытом женщины, но совсем не народной целительницы.

Answer (score 1):

А при чём здесь народная целительница? Здесь имеется в виду гадалка, а гадалки раньше были пожилые, бабушки, поэтому и поговорка сейчас в двух вариантах: бабка и бабушка надвое сказала. А уж "к бабке не ходи" - так это точно к гадалке, смысл: и без гадалки ясно. Это сейчас развелись гадалки, прорицательницы, целительницы всякие бабушки Марфы, а им 30 лет и наверняка шарлатанки, а раньше бабушки умели это делать и денег не брали

http://xn-----6kcabbaabboxo4a0bhu0aw6d.xn--p1ai/

Comment: Людмила, это всё очень хорошо, но вы по сути просто мой вопрос своими словами пересказали вместо ответа. Гадалка - она бабка, не сомневаюсь. Но в каком из двух значений: бабушка или знахарка. Эти два значения даёт Кузнецов, самостоятельного значения у бабки нет. Ну а источник ваш, простите, ниже всякой критики.

Comment: Да я не как источник ссылку дала, а просто рассуждения побольше. А источник здесь как-то и не нужен. Если только этимология - вон в Викисловаре есть: поговорка "бабка надвое сказала "произошла от пословицы путём усечения: «Бабушка гадала, да надвое сказала: то ли дождь, то ли снег; то ли будет, то ли нет». Просто я хотела сказать, что не вижу "стёртости " значений, всё равно в поговорке имеется в виду не просто бабушка, а именно гадалка,предсказательница, пусть и знахарка (та, которую ведьмой, ведуньей, колдуньей называли когда-то), но не целительница. Целительницы не гадают, а лечат.

Comment: Далеко не все бабушки этим занимались. Умудрённые опытом гадать не будут, они погоду по приметам угадывают, а не говорят: "То ли будет, то ли нет". Эти выражения иронические, я уверена, что имеются в виду не все бабушки, а именно гадалки, которым верить нельзя, как и их гаданиям на кофейной гуще.

Comment: И у Ефремовой, и у Ожегова бабка во втором значении - устаревшее "повивальная бабка", но ведь повивальная бабка и гадалка - не одно и то же. Про всяких гадалок, экстрасенсов всерьёз и не говорили, потому и в словаре их нет, а народ под "бабкой " понимал всех "ведуний", а вот это значение не устарело.

Answer (score 1):

https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0

Этимология
Выражение образовано усечением пословицы «Бабушка гадала, да надвое сказала: то ли дождь, то ли снег; то ли будет, то ли нет».

Значение слова Бабка по Ефремовой:
1. ж. разг. То же, что: бабушка. 
2. Женщина, помогавшая при родах. Знахарка.

Думаю, что в данном контексте все же ближе будет значение "знахарка". И вообще, сами понятия "устаревшее и разговорное" можно применить практически ко всем пословицам, поговоркам и большинству фразеологизмов.

Comment: А обосновать можете, что знахарка? Людмила вон принципиально против.

Comment: Но "мольфар" - это уже уже не дословный перевод. Бабуся? Бабця? Бабуня? Баба? - что выберете, если переводить на украинский?

Comment: *И потом, Людмила сказала почти то же, что и я* - Ась? Она говорит, что тут нет значения "знахарка", то есть п. 1. по Ефремовой, а Вы - про п. 2. Интересное у вас "тоже"   получается...

Comment: Я сейчас созвонюсь с украинскими филологами. И напишу позже. И насколько я понимаю, то Людмила возражала только по поводу "народных целителей" в их современной интерпритации и настаивала, что бабка - это гадалка, пожилая женщина

Comment: По мнению моих знакомых филологов не возможен дословный перевод данных выражений - фраза потеряет весь смысл. Попробуйте воспользоваться словарями фразеологизмов и устойчивых выражений для поиска сходных по значению фразеологизмов в необходимых Вам языках.

Comment: Передайте "знакомым филологам", что есть такое понятие, как буквальный перевод. http://www.refegrad.ru/index.php?id=415. Не о смысле спрашиваю, а значении одного слова. Впрочем, в нашем случае,  фраза не теряет смысл даже при нем.

Comment: "Бабка надвоє гадала", "до бабок не ходи". И бабка здесь именно в значении знахарка, гадалка

Comment: Ну это я уже слышал. Вернулись к началу разговора. Обоснования нет. Ладно спасибо, здесь не любят длинных обсуждений в комментариях.

Answer (score 0):

Бабка, конечно, простонародное выражение, ближе к сказочному: бабка, дедка, детка, репка... Никто ведь не напишет в официальном документе "курочка", ну только если речь не идет о конфетах "Курочка Ряба".